# Why web form does not fire any event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, .net-4.0

I have web application using .NET 4.0, it has a web form which contain buttons, grid view along with link button, Model popup along with user controls which have button itself.

When i am clicking on this buttons of web form it does not fire any event.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdGetList" runat="server" Text="Get List" OnClick="cmdGetList_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <ucTega:AgencyOfcDtls ID="ucAgencyDtls" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why this happened with my web application?

Comment: Can you post your HTML/ASP.Net code and the code behind as well ? Difficult to troubleshoot without seeing the code.

Comment: i edited my html code,which have user control ucAgencyDtls it having gridview

Comment: Please can you post your code behind, in particular the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say you'r calling DataBind on your GridView on every page load. It's something which will be very difficult to debug unless you've experienced the problem already.